# uncompress files from a tar using apache commons - prob is duplicate entry

Tags: java, tar, apache-commons

**Scenario:** Uncompress a tar file using Apache commons.

**Problem:** The tar i am using is a build tar which gets deployed into a web server. This tar contains duplicate entries like below.

1. appender_class.xml
2. APPENDER_CLASS.xml

when extracting using the below code only appender_class.xml is extracted but i want both the files how can i do that ? Renaming in fly is fine but how can i accomplish that?

```
public static void untar(File[] files) throws Exception {
        String path = files[0].toString();
        File tarPath = new File(path);
        TarEntry entry;
        TarInputStream inputStream = null;
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new TarInputStream(new FileInputStream(tarPath));
            while (null != (entry = inputStream.getNextEntry())) {
                int bytesRead;
                System.out.println("tarpath:" + tarPath.getName());
                System.out.println("Entry:" + entry.getName());
                String pathWithoutName = path.substring(0, path.indexOf(tarPath.getName()));
                System.out.println("pathname:" + pathWithoutName);
                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    File directory = new File(pathWithoutName + entry.getName());
                    directory.mkdir();
                    continue;
                }
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(pathWithoutName + entry.getName());
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                System.out.println("Extracted " + entry.getName());
            }
    }
```

Comment: What operating system?  That code should work fine as long as you're running on a case-sensitive file system.

Comment: yes as @mrhobo mentioned below i am extracting in a windows file system where as the tar is created in UNIX file system.

Comment: On a case insensitive system it's not possible to create two different files whose names differ only by case, so there's no way to extract such a tar faithfully on a typical Windows FS, you will have to rename one or the other of the entries (and it depends what the tar file contents will be used for as to whether this is safe and which one you can change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try opening your FileOutputstream like this instead:

```
File outputFile = new File(pathWithoutName + entry.getName());
for(int i = 2; outputFile.exists(); i++) {
    outputFile = new File(pathWithoutName + entry.getName() + i);
}
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

It should generate a file called APPENDER_CLASS.xml2 if it encounters a previously created file called APPENDER_CLASS.xml. If a APPENDER_CLASS.xml2 exists it will create a APPENDER_CLASS.xml3, ad infinitum.

File.exists() takes case sensitivity into account (windows filenames are case insensitive, whereas unix, linux and mac are case sensitive). Thus with the above code on case insensitive filesystems the file would be renamed and on case sensitive filesystems the file would not be renamed.